# Filtering a spark dataframe based on date

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of

```
date, string, string
```

I want to select dates before a certain period. I have tried the following with no luck

```
 data.filter(data("date") < new java.sql.Date(format.parse("2015-03-14").getTime))
```

I'm getting an error stating the following

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) date#75 missing from date#72,uid#73,iid#74 in operator !Filter (date#75 < 16508);
```

As far as I can guess the query is incorrect. Can anyone show me what way the query should be formatted?

I checked that all enteries in the dataframe have values - they do.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The following solutions are applicable since **spark 1.5** :

For lower than :

```scala
// filter data where the date is lesser than 2015-03-14
data.filter(data("date").lt(lit("2015-03-14")))
```

For greater than :

```scala
// filter data where the date is greater than 2015-03-14
data.filter(data("date").gt(lit("2015-03-14")))
```

For equality, you can use either `equalTo` or `===` :

```scala
data.filter(data("date") === lit("2015-03-14"))
```

If your `DataFrame` date column is of type `StringType`, you can convert it using the `to_date` function :

```scala
// filter data where the date is greater than 2015-03-14
data.filter(to_date(data("date")).gt(lit("2015-03-14")))
```

You can also filter according to a year using the `year` function :

```scala
// filter data where year is greater or equal to 2016
data.filter(year($"date").geq(lit(2016)))
```

Comment: Is there any option like `between` for date column in spark? Also i have date in 'dd/MM/yyyy' format.

Comment: @Sivailango Of course, it's filter on between, check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938806/how-to-filter-date-range-using-data-bricks-in-apache-spark/33939650#33939650)

Comment: `df.select(df("ID"), date_format(df("Week_Ending_Date"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
.filter(date_format(df("Week_Ending_Date"), "yyyy-MM-dd").between("2015-07-05", "2015-09-02"))`  Is it right? Also i am looking your another answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938806/how-to-filter-date-range-using-data-bricks-in-apache-spark

Comment: is there any way to tell gt o lt to be like now - 5 months? or i just have to calculate that date and give it to the function as string

Comment: If you want to use current date with date diff, comparing dates will be different.

Comment: Can we find null values in timestamp column?

Comment: @Darshan if the column is null. You can examine it with the isNull function predicate whatever the time is.

Comment: `lit` is in `pyspark.sql.functions` if you can't find it.

Answer (score 25):

Don't use this as suggested in other answers

```
.filter(f.col("dateColumn") < f.lit('2017-11-01'))
```

But use this instead

```
.filter(f.col("dateColumn") < f.unix_timestamp(f.lit('2017-11-01 00:00:00')).cast('timestamp'))
```

This will use the `TimestampType` instead of the `StringType`, which will be more performant in some cases. For example Parquet predicate pushdown will only work with the latter.

*Edit:* Both snippets assume this import:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
```

Comment: What is `f`? Also, please share the imports

Comment: Good point. I've added them to the answer.

Answer (score 21):

I find the most readable way to express this is using a sql expression:

```
df.filter("my_date < date'2015-01-01'")
```

we can verify this works correctly by looking at the physical plan from `.explain()`

```
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(my_date#22) && (my_date#22 < 16436))
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but .filter("effectivedate > to_date('1900-02-02')") did work (for the situation related to me).  Most likely I need some library loaded for the given solution to work.   But all in all this was the best answer.

Comment: Strange - it should work in vanilla pyspark.

Answer (score 9):

In PySpark(python) one of the option is to have the column in unix_timestamp format.We can convert string to unix_timestamp and specify the format as shown below.
Note we need to import unix_timestamp and lit function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, lit

df.withColumn("tx_date", to_date(unix_timestamp(df_cast["date"], "MM/dd/yyyy").cast("timestamp")))
```

Now we can apply the filters

```
df_cast.filter(df_cast["tx_date"] >= lit('2017-01-01')) \
       .filter(df_cast["tx_date"] <= lit('2017-01-31')).show()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df=df.filter(df["columnname"]>='2020-01-13')
```

Comment: I think one can simply do: 
`df[ df["columnname"] >= '2020-01-13']`

Answer (score 1):

**We can also use SQL kind of expression inside filter :**

---

> Note -> Here  I am showing two conditions and a date range for future
> reference :

---

```
ordersDf.filter("order_status = 'PENDING_PAYMENT' AND order_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-31' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

imho it should be like this:

```
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Calendar
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.sql.Date

val jDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
val sqlDateTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(jDate.getTime())
val sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(jDate.getTime())

data.filter(data("date").gt(sqlDate)) 
data.filter(data("date").gt(sqlDateTime))
```