# How to filter by date range in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter the date range from the following data using Data bricks, which returns null as response.
My csv data looks like:

```
ID, Desc, Week_Ending_Date
100, AAA, 13-06-2015
101, BBB, 11-07-2015
102, CCC, 15-08-2015
103, DDD, 05-09-2015
100, AAA, 29-08-2015
100, AAA, 22-08-2015
```

My query is:

```
df.select(df("ID"), date_format(df("Week_Ending_Date"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
.filter(date_format(df("Week_Ending_Date"), "yyyy-MM-  dd").between("2015-07-05", "2015-09-02"))
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the top of my head, I would have done the following by converting the date column while reading it and then apply the filter using an alias :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
val data = sc.parallelize(
  List((100, "AAA", "13-06-2015"), (101, "BBB", "11-07-2015"), (102, "CCC", "15-08-2015"), (103, "DDD", "05-09-2015"), (100, "AAA", "29-08-2015"), (100, "AAA", "22-08-2015")).toSeq).map {
  r =>
    val date: java.sql.Date = new java.sql.Date(format.parse(r._3).getTime);
    (r._1, r._2, date)
}.toDF("ID", "Desc", "Week_Ending_Date")

data.show

//+---+----+----------------+
//| ID|Desc|Week_Ending_Date|
//+---+----+----------------+
//|100| AAA|      2015-06-13|
//|101| BBB|      2015-07-11|
//|102| CCC|      2015-08-15|
//|103| DDD|      2015-09-05|
//|100| AAA|      2015-08-29|
//|100| AAA|      2015-08-22|
//+---+----+----------------+

val filteredData = data
           .select(data("ID"), date_format(data("Week_Ending_Date"), "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("date"))
           .filter($"date".between("2015-07-05", "2015-09-02"))

//+---+----------+
//| ID|      date|
//+---+----------+
//|101|2015-07-11|
//|102|2015-08-15|
//|100|2015-08-29|
//|100|2015-08-22|
//+---+----------+
```

Comment: Instead of parallelize the values in List, already i have set of those sample values in data frame `var df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
     .option("header", "true")
     .option("inferSchema", "true")
     .load("test.csv");` this is my data frame, i have loaded the data by https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv plugin

Comment: What is your DataFrame schema? You seem to have a similar problem on a different data format...

Comment: Same schema mentioned in question

Comment: If you have the same schema then the code line for filteredData suffice. I have used the parallelize method just to create my data frame, if your dataframe is created and with the same schema, you won't need it!

Comment: it works when the date fomat is 'yyyy-MM-dd' in CSV format instead of 'dd-MM-yyyy' format in CSV.

Comment: I'm back at spark 1.3.1 where the date_format function doesn't exist yet.  I'm wondering when it is required.  This works as well:  dim.printSchema
root
 |-- start_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- end_date: string (nullable = true)

processing.printSchema
root
 |-- processing_date: string (nullable = true)

dim.join(processing).filter(processing("processing_date").geq(dim("start_date")).and(processing("processing_date").lt(dim("end_date")))).printSchema

Comment: @bruceszalwinski There is lots of ways to perform actions in spark, I have just gave one way of doing it ! :)

Comment: Ok.  I was just wondering when I had to use date_format.  It seems that there is an implicit conversion of strings to dates under the spark covers.

Comment: Consider it as a syntax sugar ! There is implicit conversion thought.

Comment: @eliasah I have similar problem , when i say ...company_df.filter($"data_date".between("2017-01-01", "2017-12-31"))                   .select(""data_date").show(5)    
Getting below error  ' 

java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: unsafe symbol Unstable (child of <none>) in runtime reflection universe
 at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.<init>(Symbols.scala:205)
 at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$TypeSymbol.<init>(Symbols.scala:3030)
 at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$ClassSymbol.<init>(Symbols.scala:3222)
 at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$StubClassSymbol.<init> '