# Scala: To check the current Timstamp is greater than a timestamp column in my dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose i have a dataframe in which Timestamp column is present.

```
Timestamp  
2016-04-19T17:13:17  
2016-04-20T11:31:31  
2016-04-20T18:44:31  
2016-04-20T14:44:01
```

I have to check whether current timsetamp is greater than `Timestamp + 1` (i.e addition of 1 day to it) column in Scala

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a spark dataframe based on date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994997/filtering-a-spark-dataframe-based-on-date)

Comment: Actually i want to check for current Timestamp not an pre-defined date.

Comment: ok but you want to filter or what ? it's not clear !

Comment: I have to check the conditions i specified and filter out in another Dataframe

Comment: Does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it liked this.

```
df.filter(date_add('column_name', 1).lt(current_timestamp()))
```

Answer (score 1):

DataFrame supports two types of `current_` on date and timestamp

Let's consider a DataFrame df with id and event_date columns.

We can perform the following filter operations :

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// the event_date is before the current timestamp
df.filter('event_date.lt(current_timestamp()))

// the event_date is after the current timestamp
df.filter('event_date.gt(current_timestamp()))
```

I advice you to read the associated scala doc for more information [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html). You have a whole section on dates and timestamps operations.

**EDIT:** As discussed in the comments, in order to add a day to your `event_date` column, you can use the `date_add`function :

```
df.filter(date_add('event_date,1).lt(current_timestamp()))
```

Comment: Thanks @eliasah it was helpful.. But suppose we want to filter 'event_date' + adding one more single day to it according to the date specified in column greater than current. Then how can we achieve it.

Comment: you can use date_add then it's also available in the doc.