# Comparing timestamps in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two columns in my db, called start_date and end_date, which are both timestamps. I want to collect only the rows that meet the requirement: start_date <= current date and end_date > current date. Right now I have

```
.select("col1", "col2", "col3")
.where(col("start_date") <= current_date())
.where(col("end_date") > current_date() && col("end_date") =!= null)
```

but this returns nothing, which gives me a reason to believe I'm comparing timestamps incorrectly. Could anyone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: [scala-to-check-the-current-timstamp-is-greater-than-a-timestamp-column-in-my-da](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36976244/5275706)

Comment: use `col("end_date").isNotNull` instead