# Pyspark Importing Column module to use gt or geq

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am following this solution with Spark 2.0.0 [Filtering a spark dataframe based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994997/filtering-a-spark-dataframe-based-on-date)

Without the Column module, I get the following error when I try to use expression gt.

```
DataFrame' object has no attribute 'gt'
```

I tried to import Column module to use expressions like lt,gt, geq etc.

```
from pyspark.sql.column import *
```

I get the error:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Any tips on how can I use gt expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pyspark` doesn't support those functions but you can still use the `operator` module as followed :

```
>>> from operator import ge
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df = spark.range(1, 50)
>>> df.filter(ge(df.id, F.lit(45))).show()
# +---+
# | id|
# +---+
# | 45|
# | 46|
# | 47|
# | 48|
# | 49|
# +---+
```

Or you can even use the `>=` operator:

```
>>> df.filter(df.id >= F.lit(45)).show()
# +---+
# | id|
# +---+
# | 45|
# | 46|
# | 47|
# | 48|
# | 49|
# +---+
```