# scala filter operation to filter the CSV file

Tags: scala

How can use Scala filter operation to filter only records/rows that contains the year 2009 and 2010.

Basically, I want to filter the csv file using Scala Filter operation, so pick all the rows that has below date column.[image]

```
07/01/2008
07/01/2009
```

I'm creating and rdd by reading the data from csv and now I want to filter the data who's year in 2009, 2010

```
val data = spark.read.csv("D:\\data.csv").rdd
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: did you see examples on the internet of the filter function? almost every tutorial shows how to use filter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a spark dataframe based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994997/filtering-a-spark-dataframe-based-on-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to create `RDD`. You can filter the data using `dataframe` itself.

You have below df

```
+-------+-----------+
|country|       year|
+-------+-----------+
|  India| 07-01-2009|
|    USA| 07-01-2010|
|    USA| 01-01-2008|
|  India| 07-01-2010|
| Canada| 07-01-2009|
| Canada| 02-03-2018|
+-------+-----------+
```

Create one more `column` filter_year

```
val newdf=df.withColumn("filter_year",substring(df.col("year"),8,10))

+-------+-----------+-----------+
|country|       year|filter_year|
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  India| 07-01-2009|       2009|
|    USA| 07-01-2010|       2010|
|    USA| 01-01-2008|       2008|
|  India| 07-01-2010|       2010|
| Canada| 07-01-2009|       2009|
| Canada| 02-03-2018|       2018|
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

Now apply `filter` condition and `drop` the new added `column`

```
val ans=newdf.filter("filter_year in (2009,2010)").drop("filter_year")

+-------+-----------+
|country|       year|
+-------+-----------+
|  India| 07-01-2009|
|    USA| 07-01-2010|
|  India| 07-01-2010|
| Canada| 07-01-2009|
+-------+-----------+
```

If you have `RDD` of given data then you can do like below

```
val rdd=spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter",",").load("C:\\spark\\programs\\temp.csv").rdd
```

RDD will be look like this

```
 Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([India, 07-01-2009], [USA, 07-01-2010], [USA, 01-01-2008], [India, 07-01-2010], [Canada, 07-01-2009], [Canada, 02-03-2018])
```

You need to write only below line of code carefully for your dataset

```
 val yearList=List(2009,2010)

 rdd.filter(Row=>yearList.contains(Row(1).toString.trim.split("-")(2).toInt)).collect
```

You will get your desire output like below

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([India, 07-01-2009], [USA, 07-01-2010], [India, 07-01-2010], [Canada, 07-01-2009])
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj using the DataFrame seems to best the solution.