# Filtering a DataFrame on date columns comparison

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter a DataFrame comparing two date columns using Scala and Spark. Based on the filtered DataFrame there are calculations running on top to calculate new columns. 
Simplified my data frame has the following schema:

```
|-- received_day: date (nullable = true)
|-- finished: int (nullable = true)
```

On top of that I create two new column `t_start` and `t_end` that would be used for filtering the DataFrame. They have 10 and 20 days difference from the original column `received_day`:

```
val dfWithDates= df
      .withColumn("t_end",date_sub(col("received_day"),10))
      .withColumn("t_start",date_sub(col("received_day"),20))
```

I now want to have a new calculated column that indicates for each row of data how many rows of the dataframe are in the `t_start` to `t_end` period. I thought I can achieve this the following way:

```
val dfWithCount = dfWithDates
       .withColumn("cnt", lit(
        dfWithDates.filter(
          $"received_day".lt(col("t_end")) 
          && $"received_day".gt(col("t_start"))).count()))
```

However, this count only returns 0 and I believe that the problem is in the the argument that I am passing to `lt` and `gt`.

From following that issue here [Filtering a spark dataframe based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994997/filtering-a-spark-dataframe-based-on-date) I realized that I need to pass a string value. If I try with hard coded values like `lt(lit("2018-12-15"))`, then the filtering works. So I tried casting my columns to `StringType`:

```
val dfWithDates= df
      .withColumn("t_end",date_sub(col("received_day"),10).cast(DataTypes.StringType))
      .withColumn("t_start",date_sub(col("received_day"),20).cast(DataTypes.StringType))
```

But the filter still returns an empty dataFrame. 
I would assume that I am not handling the data type right.

I am running on Scala 2.11.0 with Spark 2.0.2.

Comment: Maybe also someone knows where I can find the documentation on `lt()` and `gt()`? I tried searching for it but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: You can find all functions operable on `Column` Data types here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. For `$"received_day".lt(col("t_end")` each `reveived_day` value is compared with the current row's `t_end` value, not the whole dataframe. So each time you'll get zero as count. 
You can solve this by writing a simple udf. Here is the way how you can solve the issue:

**Creating sample input dataset**:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import java.sql.Date
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq((Date.valueOf("2018-10-12"),1),
              (Date.valueOf("2018-10-13"),1),
              (Date.valueOf("2018-09-25"),1),
              (Date.valueOf("2018-10-14"),1)).toDF("received_day", "finished")

val dfWithDates= df
  .withColumn("t_start",date_sub(col("received_day"),20))
  .withColumn("t_end",date_sub(col("received_day"),10))
dfWithDates.show()
    +------------+--------+----------+----------+
|received_day|finished|   t_start|     t_end|
+------------+--------+----------+----------+
|  2018-10-12|       1|2018-09-22|2018-10-02|
|  2018-10-13|       1|2018-09-23|2018-10-03|
|  2018-09-25|       1|2018-09-05|2018-09-15|
|  2018-10-14|       1|2018-09-24|2018-10-04|
+------------+--------+----------+----------+
```

Here for `2018-09-25` we desire count 3

**Generate output**:

```
val count_udf = udf((received_day:Date) => {
        (dfWithDates.filter((col("t_end").gt(s"$received_day")) && col("t_start").lt(s"$received_day")).count())
    })
    val dfWithCount = dfWithDates.withColumn("count",count_udf(col("received_day")))
    dfWithCount.show()
    +------------+--------+----------+----------+-----+
|received_day|finished|   t_start|     t_end|count|
+------------+--------+----------+----------+-----+
|  2018-10-12|       1|2018-09-22|2018-10-02|    0|
|  2018-10-13|       1|2018-09-23|2018-10-03|    0|
|  2018-09-25|       1|2018-09-05|2018-09-15|    3|
|  2018-10-14|       1|2018-09-24|2018-10-04|    0|
+------------+--------+----------+----------+-----+
```

To make computation faster i would suggest to cache `dfWithDates` as there are  repetition of same operation for each row.

Comment: This would actually work for me, I just cannot understand why was your answer downgraded without any comment. Is there something in it that is not good practice?

Comment: @Inna Still i don't understand why it is downgraded. Downgrading without any comment is not acceptable. You asked a good question and at first i saw the question is downgraded without any comment. Can you please accept the answer if  it works ?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast date value to string with any pattern using DateTimeFormatter

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Comment: This works if I have a `val t_end` that is `DateTime` format but if I try to do `.withColumn("t_end",date_sub(col("received_day"),10).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")))`  I get the following error: `error: value format is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column`